# How to add search score of a document while converting solr search response to POJO using solrj

Tags: java, search, solr, lucene, solrj

I am using SolrJ to interact with Solr instance. I simply want to get search score of each document returned by Solr for a particular search query. If I add a score field in my POJO with @Field annotation it works totally fine while retrieving documents. When I try to index something through the same POJO, Solr returns an error saying unknown field "score", as I do not have any field named "score" in my Solr schema. But, if I add a field named "score" in my Solr schema it starts returning the default value of score instead of search score. Please suggest me how to solve this problem. I do not want to iterate through all the documents one by one and add the score to POJO. I am performing following steps :

```
public void getSolrResult(String query) {
 SolrQuery query = new SolrQuery();
 query.set("q", query);
 query.set("fl", "*, score");
 QueryResponse queryResponse = solrjClient.query(query);
 solrResult = queryResponse.getBeans(PojoSolr.class);
}
Class PojoSolr {

 //Other fields
 @Field("score")
 private float searchScore;

 public float getSearchScore(){
  return searchScore;
 }
 public void setSearchScore(float score) {
  this.searchScore = score;
 }
}
```

Comment: `score` is calculated dynamically during search, it's not a static value.

Comment: @EricWang : I know that the score is not a static field.

Answer (score 0):

I solved a similar problem like this using inheritance.

Simply move the score field down to a sub-class. Use the base class for indexing and the sub-class for querying.

```
class PojoSolr {
    //Other fields
}
class PojoSolrOutput extends PojoSolr {
    @Field("score")
    private float searchScore;
}
```

Note that there are also use cases for the other way round, e.g. fields that are not stored and can thus not be retrieved, but must be indexed.
In this case another sub-class `PojoSolrInput` containing these fields makes sense.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

My 30-minutes search on this topic lead me only to this SO post and:

1. http://lucene.472066.n3.nabble.com/How-to-get-the-score-in-the-result-td493812.html
2. http://lucene.472066.n3.nabble.com/Scoring-using-POJO-SolrJ-td3235016.html

In the second it's suggested to remove the `@Field` annotation from score, but it does not work. In both places no valid solution has been proposed.

So I came up with the solution of cycling on the "raw" results, binding them as `getBeans` does, and adding the score:

```
SolrDocumentList sdl = response.getResults();
List<T> documents = new LinkedList<>();
for (SolrDocument sd : sdl) {
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    T sb = (T) getClient().getBinder().getBean(<T class>, sd);
    sb.setScore((Float) sd.get("score"));
    documents.add(sb);
}
```